# Can I save an object as a config var in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

So I've read the Heroku config vars docs, and want to save an object as a config var - rather than save each member of the object separately. Is this possible? I tried to copy/paste it into Heroku's config var setup as JSON, but the node app doesn't seem to be able to access it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config vars are all strings. If you've got your JSON string in a config var, you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks - should have thought of that!